# Java Swing: What is a good solution to implement a info window?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am currently programming a little tool in java with swing elements.

I want an external window to pop up when clicking on a menu button. Now im questioning what the best/a good way to implement that?

My current solution is a JOptionPane with a few JLabels in it.

```
public void optionpane_about_ShowDialog() {
JComponent[] testArray = {
  label_about_versionAutor, label_about_links};
optionpane_about.showMessageDialog(this, testArray, "Info", optionpane_about.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

I'm fine with that solution, despite it maybe being a bit odd.

But i have one problem that i don't know a solution to, with that way:
The labels included allow me to have a border around them, but only around one label, not two (If it's possible, it would be nice to know how ;) )

I read about solutions on how to make an info pop up window, from OptionPanes to JFrames and so on.

What is the best possible solution?
Greetz. Julian

Comment: To put a border around multiple components, you can put the components into a JPanel then put the border on the JPanel.

Comment: @bcr666 I already tested putting a JPanel into an OptionPane but the OptionPane doesnt respond to the size of the Panel. Is there a solution im missing?

Comment: There are a myriad of ways to make a popup window, but you have to weigh the options of which each does. JDialogs for example can be modal and block anything else in your application until the dialog is closed.

Comment: for the JPanel solution, use setPreferredSize as well as setSize

Comment: Thanks @ControlAltDel, now it works just fine.

Comment: Hint: `JOptionPane` (and some other Swing components) accept (simple) HTML code: [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)